# Passing arguments in function

Tags: php, sonata

I am trying to refactor a subset of my code as practice and since I am new at `Sonata`. I am making a silly mistake but I am stuck at reconciling my mistake:

```
public function getIsActiveThisYear(EndDate $endDate,StartDate $startDate): bool
 {
     return  $this->$endDate == $date->isCurrentYear() || $this->$startDate == $date->isCurrentYear();
 }
```

I am receiving the following error: `No arguments passed`. Keep in mind while answering this question I could be making an obvious mistake or doing it all wrong; a good description will help me learn. Thanks!

This is the full error

```
1) App\Tests\Entity\ProjectTest::testProjectEndsSameYearIsActiveThisYear
ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Entity\Project::getIsActiveThisYear(), 0 passed in /media/dmogaka/CENTOS/LivegeneBackend/livegene_backend/tests/Entity/ProjectTest.php on line 83 and exactly 2 expected
```

Comment: What's the full error? And can you show us the code where you _call_ this method? And the method signature for `isCurrentYear`.

Comment: @Jonnix i have added the full error message

Comment: So you've called `getIsActiveThisYear` without any arguments, but you can see it requires 2 just as the errors messages says. It even tells you where you're doing it.